# Validation if an integer type property in a list object is sequential and not duplicate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have a class whose has a list type property:

```
public class FormDTO
{
    public List<FieldDTO> FormFields { get; set; }
}

public class FieldDTO
{
    public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I want to check if the `SequenceNumber` property in the `FormField` is sequential, non-repeating.

- Valid result [1,2,3,4,5,6...]
- Invalid result [1,2,4,5,6] or [1,2,2,3,4,5]

I need a rule for this by using fluent validation.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution by writing a custom method:

```
public Validator()
{
RuleFor(x => x.FormFields).Must(IsSequentAndOrdered);
}

private bool IsSequentAndOrdered(List<FieldDTO> fieldDto)
{
 return fieldDto.Select(x=> x.SequenceNumber).Skip(1).Select((v, i) 
 => v == (fieldDto[i].SequenceNumber + 1)).All(v => v);
}
```